# python numpy mutate selection

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, selection

i encountered a strange bug(?) in numpy:
Given a nested array:

```
p = np.asarray([[1., 2., 3.], [-4., -5., -6.], [1,2,-4]], dtype=np.float32)
```

which is

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
   [-4., -5., -6.],
   [ 1.,  2., -4.]], dtype=float32)
```

i want to mutate the third entry of the array conditional like

```
p[p[:, 2] <0][:, 2] *= -1
```

The last statement however does not mutate p. 
I HOPE for output like

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
   [-4., -5., 6.],
   [ 1.,  2., 4.]], dtype=float32)
```

but in fact it does nothing at all. p stays unchanged.
I tested many things and i do not come to a conclusion why p does not mutate.

Of course i can somehow work around this, but this seems strange to me.
Cheers and thanks in advance.
Daniel

Comment: Reversing the order of your square brackets should fix it, i.e. `p[:, 2][p[:, 2] < 0] *= -1`. Boolean indexing returns a copy, unless you are doing an assignment to it, which you can achieve by making it be the last indexing operation.

Comment: THIS is the answer to my question. I would mark this as correct, if i could :)

Comment: There you go, now it's an answer you can accept. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing the order of your square brackets should fix it:

```
p[:, 2][p[:, 2] < 0] *= -1
```

Boolean indexing returns a copy, unless you are doing an assignment to it, which you can achieve by making it be the last indexing operation.

Answer (score 0):

You've modified a copy of the original array. If you want to mutate original array you should use something like this:

```
p[p[:, 2] <0, 2] *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

`p[boolean_array]` returns a copy, so you modify your copy but leave your original unchanged. You could use `np.where` instead for example. Something like `p[:,2] = np.where(p[:,2], p[:,2], -p[:,2])`